# Return all labels that contain repeated elements of array

Tags: python

I have data that looks like this in python: Notice that the first and last two elements have repeats of that array.

```
 for _, m in enumerate(array)
    print(_,m)

#Output:   
    1 [2,3]
    2 [8,8]
    2 [9,7]
    3 [1,1]       
    3 [2,3]
    4 [8,8]
```

I want a function that outputs the labels only if there are repeats of that array. Something like this:

```
    [2,3]: 1,3
    [8,8]: 2,4
```

The code I want should be something like this?

```
    for _, m in enumerate(array):
      if m repeats:
        print(m, _.all())
```

Comment: The data you've described isn't valid Python. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows what exactly you're trying to accomplish -- in this case, examples would be helpful.

Comment: is that a dictionary?

Comment: @AltaïrIbn-La'Ahad, no, its just a label and array from the enumerate function

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, an interactive community. Interact with the community so they can tell if the question has been answered. If an answer meets your needs accept the answer. If the question has not been answered add comments. Possibly clarify your question. How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE) provides information to help you succeed. Creating an MRE has two benefits. You may solve the problem while creating the MRE. If, not then posting the MRE will help others provide an answer.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Man, i just need some help jesus christ

Answer (score 0):

hope this will answer to your needs, still try to follow the advice about MRE next time

lets start defining a simple function to list all positions of an element into a list

the next step would be to actually print an element one time only if it is contained 2 or more times into the "array".
this is achievable using a list to keep the items already checked (found)

```
def find_positions(n_array, to_find):
        return [i for i in [i for i in range(len(n_array))] if to_find == n_array[i]]

if __name__ == "__main__":
        array = [[2,3],[8,8],[9,7],[1,1],[2,3],[8,8]]
        found = []
        for element in array:
            if element not in found:
                found.append(element)
                position = find_positions(array, element)
                if len(position)>1:
                    print(element,":",position)
```

this above is an example of an MRE of a solution ;)

```
output:
[2,3] : [0,4]
[8,8] : [1,5]
```

Note that the indexing of the positions starts with 0, a choice to be in line with python indexing ;)

Comment: @ChelseaZou if you need some more info about the code i wrote just ask, try to modify your answer to follow MRE if you want more specific help